# What does the asio set_password_callback() method?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost-asio

Return this method a passphrase from the privatekey? Why is it needed? What should I return or whats a smart implementation? I have no idea what the meaning of this method is. 
All I found is this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_password_callback.html

Answer (score 1):

It sets the password callback.
You should return the password (a.k.a. passphrase).

The password would e.g. be required to decrypt the private key if it was protected with a password.

An example is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp

```
context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
```

And

```
std::string get_password() const
{
  return "test";
}
```

Comment: So if my certificates are in plaintext I don't need the method?

Comment: Indeed [padding]